# Specify url in facebook share button sharer.php

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I am trying to set a share button in my dynamically created webpage. I am using this code:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" share_url="TEXT" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="URL">Share</a>
```

But all I get is the original url plus my text "TEXT". I can't use the original url since it will not exists. It is just created for that moment every time. So I want to share a fixed url.

Is it possible? I haven't had any problem with google plus or twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is deprecated.

If you want to share a URL different from the current one, that is not posible anymore.

You can get more info and current code in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Exactly, right after the

```
<body>
```

you should add

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Adn then you have to add wherever you like the following:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but in my webpage it doesn't show anything. I generate X number of pages dynamically and I don't know how to solve it. With my code, I can share the content but I must share the original link also.

Comment: And what is the problem with the next code then?
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div>

Comment: The problem is that the code provided by facebook is not displayed in my webpage. Where do I have to set the first div of all: <div id="fb-root"></div> And, do I have to include any other library?

Comment: I added a complete answer if you have any problem, tell me and I'll try to solve it.

Comment: I checked your new code and it shows a word in blue: SHARE. But no icon. Also, when I go inside it says something like: you will share this, blablabla but no link is shared or shown in that page.

Comment: The problem is that the page I want to show the button is dynamically created. if I put the button in a normal page it works like a charm

Comment: Also, the button is not stable in dynamic pages. Sometimes appears, others doesn't... You refresh 5 times and maybe 2, appears. So maybe I can't use it in my webpage,

Comment: I am using it dinamically in one of my websites, so I am not sure why it is not working in yours. http://www.aquiestalanavidad.com/foto.php?id=1005

Comment: I will check tomorrow morning and tell you what I find

Comment: I did. I check the code in your webpage and copy the function and div adapting to my webpage. And it works. I don't know why it was failing . Thanks man. I had to put the code not in body tag but in every dynamic page

Comment: I'm glad of being helpful :-)